# PHP Function: make extracted words clickable?

Tags: php, function, tags, keyword

I can not make clickable extracted words with this function:

```
$text = $curTemplate['name'];
function extract_keywords($str, $minWordLen = 4, $minWordOccurrences = 1, $asArray = false)
{
    function keyword_count_sort($first, $sec)
    {
        return $sec[1] - $first[1];
    }
    $str = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}0-9 ]/', ' ', $str);
    $str = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str));

    $words = explode(' ', $str);
    $keywords = array();
    while(($c_word = array_shift($words)) !== null)
    {
        if(strlen($c_word) < $minWordLen) continue;

        $c_word = strtolower($c_word);
        if(array_key_exists($c_word, $keywords)) $keywords[$c_word][1]++;
        else $keywords[$c_word] = array($c_word, 1);
    }
    usort($keywords, 'keyword_count_sort');

    $final_keywords = array();
    foreach($keywords as $keyword_det)
    {
        if($keyword_det[1] < $minWordOccurrences) break;
        array_push($final_keywords, $keyword_det[0]);
    }
    return $asArray ? $final_keywords : implode(', ', $final_keywords);
}
//How to use

//Basic lorem ipsum text to extract the keywords
$text = "stackoverflow a language independent collaboratively edited question and answer site for programmers";

echo extract_keywords($text);
```

I would like the words in this way:

```
<a href="http://website.com/search.php?search=<?php echo extract_keywords($text); ?>"><?php echo extract_keywords($text); ?></a>
```

but don't work

in this way work but without the keyword in the link :(   why????

```
<a href="http://website.com/search.php?search=NO KEY"><?php echo extract_keywords($text); ?></a>
```

Comment: What exactly are you getting in your generated HTML? What does `var_dump(extract_keywords($test))` show you?

Comment: i think the solution is here:

Comment: i think the solution is here return $asArray ? $final_keywords : implode(', ', $final_keywords); <---------------  in final_keywords how to add the <a href="" parameter?

Comment: are you looking to make each individual keyword a different link? then either build the html inside your function, or always return an array.

Comment: yes i want individual keywords with a differetn link please post here the solution if you have it :(  please :)

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want the keywords as separate links?

Comment: Why don't you just return them as an array and loop through them. You have the parameter available to you within your function declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned:

```
$keywords = extract_keywords($text, 4, 1, true);

foreach($keywords as $k => $keyword){
    echo '<a href="http://website.com/search.php?search=' .  $keyword . '">' . $keyword . '</a>' . ($k != (count($keywords) - 1) ? ',' : '');
}
```

Comment: Thank you @trickyzter :)  Now work!  but how to separate the individual keywords with a comma  (,)

Comment: See update above. Please mark answer as correct if this solves your problem. ;)

Comment: Ok! Than you very much! You can test it here:  http://apps.facebook.com/cover-maker/